# Equivalent of apns-collapse-id in FCM on iOS in Xamarin Form

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is their any equivalent of apns-collapse-id for FCM. I am trying to send the apns-collapse-id as a header request but it is not collapsing the messages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `collapse_key` field, like this:

```
{
   "collapse_key" : "message_counter",
   "to" : "xyz",
   "notification": {
      "title" : "New messages",
      "body" : "You have 10 new messages",
      "badge" : 10
   },
   "data" : {
     "key1" : "value1",
     "key2" : "value2"
   },
 }
```

You can use up to 4 collapse keys per registration token (i.e. per device) and up to 100 notifications can be stored without collapsing.

If your device is offline and is sent multiple collapsible messages, it will only receive the last one (per collapse key) when it comes back online.

See the documentation on [collapsible and non-collapsible messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#collapsible_and_non-collapsible_messages) in the Firebase documentation for more information.

Comment: I want only the recent notification to be displayed , ignoring the old one with the same collapse id .

Comment: Isn't that what it does?

Comment: collapse_key is meant to collapse undelivered messages when the state of device is changed to online from offline.

Comment: If you override HandleIntent in your FirebaseMessagingService you can get the behaviour you want when the device is online (it will be called even when your app is backgrounded). Implement the SendNotification function from the Xamarin [sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-fcm/) and use the same notification id for all notifications with the same collapse_id. Newer ones will overwrite the older ones. If you don't call the base method in HandleIntent then you won't get two copies either.